# Java Runtime Environment Missionary or Corrupted

Tags: java, mysql, windows, swing, launch4j

I want to convert my POS Sales Application from a jar to exe. I keep on receiving this error(This application was configured to use a bundled Java Runtime Environment but the Runtime is missing or corrupted).How can I overcome this?

I made the POS System using Eclipse and it's connected to a database. It's not a complex project but just a simple one.

The project consists with a login page then it redirects to the main page (point of sales GUI).

I tried creating the jar file specifically for the login page and create a folder on my desktop and copied the JRE files from Java to the create Exe named folder on my desktop.

I used Launch4j to create the exe.

So, I need to be able run the exe file, It won't run. It keep on giving me that error...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.